# Error "Vuex do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers" when no mutation outside vuex occurs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a mutation defined inside Vuex that looks like this:

```
setError(state, error) {
    state.error = error
    setTimeout(() => {
      state.error = null
    }, 5000)
  },
```

And I call it like this:

```
...
catch (error) {
          this.$store.commit('setError', error.response.data.error.message)
        }
...
```

When the timeout period expires, I get an error: `[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` I don't get it, because I'm not mutating anything outside of Vuex.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

I could fix this by simplifying `setError` to just assigning the error and dropping the `setTimeout` part, but I had to do this elsewhere like this:

```
flashError(message) {
      this.$store.commit('setError', message)
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$store.commit('setError', null)
      }, 5000)
    },
```

This solution seems suboptimal because I want to be able to set this error temporarily everywhere

Many thanks

Comment: It might help to explain the reason why you are setting state.error to error, and then calling setTimeout to set it to null.  Doesn't make sense to me at face value.  Regardless, setTimeout is asynchronous, so you would need to call it in an action, not a mutation.

Comment: Good question, I'm a beginner, so perhaps it's not a good idea. I want to display a flash error message and right now I have it set up such that if the error is not null, a div will be displayed otherwise it'll be hidden. I don't want to leave the error message floating, I want it to be cleared automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comment exchange, I created a sample component that demonstrates how to auto close a flash error without involving Vuex.

```
<template>
  <div class="flash-error-auto-close">
    <h4>Flash Error with Auto Close</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="triggerTimedErrorDisplay">Show Flash Error</button>
        <div id="flash-error" v-if="displayError" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          {{ errorMessage }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        errorMessage: 'This is the error message',
        displayError: false,
        displayTime: 5000
      }
    },
    methods: {
      triggerTimedErrorDisplay() {
        this.displayError = true;

        setTimeout( () => {
          this.displayError = false;
        }, this.displayTime);
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  #flash-error {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>
```